# Odoo new module language translation

Tags: python-2.7, csv, odoo-8, po

I have created a new module. I want to translate it in Arabic.
I have **.csv** file, I want to convert it into **.po** file.

Is there any **opensource tool except poedit** to do conversion.

or Is there anything when I create fields in Python,to get .po file automatically.